# Wake Apple TV 4K via network?

Tags: swift, udp, apple-tv, wake-on-lan

I have an Apple TV 4K. I want to wake the Apple TV via network. It is connected to Ethernet cable.

I want to send a command via an iOS app connected to the same network able to see the Apple TV.

I have searched quite a bit and I have come across the _server.proxy.udp concept. I’ve read about the wake on lan magic packets approach and I have seen tools that can send those magic packets to wake the Apple TV.

However I am not sure how to send those signals natively using swift. I am not sure what the exact signal should be.

Does anyone know the exact signal to send over the network to wake the Apple TV?

Comment: To send a magic packet, you need to know: 1) the MAC address of the machine you want to wake and 2) the broadcast address of the local network segment.  The sender of the packet will need to be in the same network segment as the AppleTV (in other words, they'll each need to have the same broadcast address).  Finally, you'll need to configure the AppleTV to respond to the wake-on-LAN packet.

Comment: Unfortunately there seems to be no way to wake the Apple TV via lan. Even tools that send those type of commands don’t work with Apple TV.