# Is there a way to turn on my Apple TV via my Raspberry Pi (Wifi, Bluetooth)?

Tags: python, node.js, raspberry-pi3, apple-tv

I am trying to automate some stuff and it's all going fine but I am a bit stuck, I can turn my tv on/off via a HTTP request but I was wondering if I could do something similar to turn on my Apple TV. My Apple TV is running tvOS 16.5.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/73563240/2836621

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.